# In material ui datgrid export button how to call other function as well as download the file

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHSDF.png  here when i click on any button it will call onefunction alongwith there functionality.

I used

CustomToolbar = () => {
return (

{(params) => (
<>
<GridCsvExportMenuItem onClick={()=>this.handleCsvExport(params)} />
<GridPrintExportMenuItem onClick={()=>this.handleCsvExport(params)} />
{/* Add more export options if needed */}
</>
)}

```
      </GridToolbarExportContainer> 
  );
};
here function handleCsvExport is called but file neither download neither print
```